# Unable to expand a ExpandableListView in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

[Edit]- Changing question framing: How to use Android ExpandableListView inside a ScrollView?

I am implementing a ExpandableListView in Android. So whenever I click on the arrow to expand i.e calling setOnGroupExpandListener. The list expands inside the group itself. I want it below it. I am attaching the code .

drawable_list_group.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@color/grey_transparent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_dark_material_dark" />

</LinearLayout>
```

drawable_list_item.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="@color/highlighted_text_material_light"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

preferences_content.xml(not from start)

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/cuisine_preference_linear_layout"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/component_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cuisine_preference_label"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/component_margin"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/component_margin"
                android:text="Cuisines"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/subheading_text_size" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/component_margin"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/component_margin"
                android:text="Choose your 3 favourite cuisines:"
                android:textSize="@dimen/subheading_text_size" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/horizontal_line"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/table_row_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/table_row_padding"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/component_margin"
                android:background="@color/whiteGrey"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>

            <ExpandableListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/lvExp">

            </ExpandableListView>



        </LinearLayout>
```

ExpandableListAdapter.java

```
package com.fonduetech.cravy.adapter;

import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.fonduetech.cravy.R;

/**
 * Created by admin on 05-Aug-15.
 */
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {


        private Context _context;
        private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
        // child data in format of header title, child title
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

        public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                     HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
            this._context = context;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .get(childPosititon);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                                 boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawable_list_item, null);
            }

            TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

            txtListChild.setText(childText);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return this._listDataHeader.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                                 View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawable_list_group, null);
            }

            TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

PreferenceActivity.java

```
package com.fonduetech.cravy;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.fonduetech.cravy.adapter.ExpandableListAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;

public class PreferenceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preference);

        Util.overrideFonts(PreferenceActivity.this, findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout));

  // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener OnGroupExpandListener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Cuisines");


        // Adding child data
        List<String> cuisineList = new ArrayList<String>();
        cuisineList.add("American");
        cuisineList.add("Oriental");
        cuisineList.add("Chinese");
        cuisineList.add("Continental");
        cuisineList.add("French");
        cuisineList.add("Italian");
        cuisineList.add("Middle Eastern");
        cuisineList.add("Mediterranean");
        cuisineList.add("Mexican");
        cuisineList.add("Thai");
        cuisineList.add("Indian");


        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), cuisineList); // Header, Child data


    }
}
```

Edit: I have found the problem and solution as well.
Chekc out answers section
Cheers!

Comment: Instead of posting answer in your question, post it in answer section which is below..